# DropDown Blazor

Tags: html, c#, .net, blazor

Como faço para a dropdown de Sub Categorias trazer os dados de acordo com o que escolhi na tabela categorias ? Eu consigo fazer puxar apenas do banco de dados porém não sei como faço a sub categoria puxar do banco dependendo de qual categoria escolhida

```
    <h1>Abrir Chamado</h1>

    @if (_ListaCategorias.Count == 0)
    {
        <p>Carregando...</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <select  class="form-control">
                    <option> Selecione uma categoria </option>
                    @foreach (var cat in _ListaCategorias)
                    {
                        <option value="@cat.IdCategoria">@cat.Descricao</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
<div class="container text-center">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value="1"> Selecione uma Subcategoria</option>
                @foreach (var sub in _ListaSubCategorias)
                {
                    <option value="@sub.">@sub.Descricao</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@code {


    private List<Categoria> _ListaCategorias = new List<Categoria>();
    private List<SubCategoria> _ListaSubCategorias = new List<SubCategoria>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Categoria _Categoria = new Categoria();
        _ListaCategorias = await _Categoria.GetCategoriasAsync();

        SubCategoria _SubCategoria = new SubCategoria();
        _ListaSubCategorias = await _SubCategoria.GetSubCategoriasAsync();


    }


    private string Categoria { get; set; }

    private string CheckSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return Categoria;
        }
        set
        {
            ChangeEventArgs selectedEventArgs = new ChangeEventArgs();
            selectedEventArgs.Value = value;
            OnChangeSelected(selectedEventArgs);
        }
    }

    private void OnChangeSelected(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
            Categoria = e.Value.ToString();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Queria fazer isso com o onchange mas não sei como

Comment: Deu certo o exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi montar um exemplo com dados `Fakes` para ilustrar a sua duvida, tem as classes `Item`, `SubItem` e `Datas` (*que representa a parte do resgate de informações do banco de dados ou qualquer repositório de informação*):

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SubItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
}

public class Datas
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
    public List<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; } = new List<SubItem>();
    public Datas()
    {
        Items.Add(new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Item 1" });
        Items.Add(new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Item 2" });
        SubItems.Add(new SubItem { Id = 1, Name = "Sub Item 1", ItemId = 1 });
        SubItems.Add(new SubItem { Id = 2, Name = "Sub Item 2", ItemId = 1 });
        SubItems.Add(new SubItem { Id = 3, Name = "Sub Item 3", ItemId = 2 });
        SubItems.Add(new SubItem { Id = 4, Name = "Sub Item 4", ItemId = 2 });
        SubItems.Add(new SubItem { Id = 5, Name = "Sub Item 5", ItemId = 2 });
    }
}
```

---

Com o evento `@onchange`: o método criado com o nome `HandleOnChange` vai te mostrar o item selecionado com o parâmetro `ChangeEventArgs e` que tem um propriedade `Value` com o valor selecionado no `<select />` e após alterar as variáveis é carregado o `SubItems` com um filtro, exemplo:

```
<select @onchange="HandleOnChange">
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
    }
</select>
<select>
    @foreach (var item in SubItems)
    {
        <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
    }
</select>
@code {
    private Models.Datas Datas = new Models.Datas();

    private int ItemIdSelected { get; set; }
    private List<Models.Item> Items { get; set; }
    private List<Models.SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }

    private void HandleOnChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            ItemIdSelected = int.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
            SubItems = Datas.SubItems
              .Where(x => x.ItemId == ItemIdSelected)
              .ToList();
        }
    }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Items = Datas.Items;
        ItemIdSelected = Items.Count > 0 ? Items[0].Id : 0;
        SubItems = Datas.SubItems.Where(x => x.ItemId == ItemIdSelected).ToList();
    }
}
```

---

Com `@bind`: o código simplifica bastante onde o opção selecionado é manipulada por um variável `ItemIdSelected` e é com essa variável o filtro deve ser feito para a outra seleção (`<select />`), exemplo:

```
<select @bind="ItemIdSelected">
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
    }
</select>
<select>
    @foreach (var item in Datas.SubItems
        .Where(x => x.ItemId == ItemIdSelected)
        .ToList()
    )
    {
        <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
    }
</select>


@code {
    private Models.Datas Datas = new Models.Datas();

    private int ItemIdSelected { get; set; } = 0;
    private List<Models.Item> Items { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Items = Datas.Items;
        ItemIdSelected = Items.Count > 0 ? Items[0].Id : 0;
    }
}
```